# use pig to generate word frequency vector

Tags: machine-learning, apache-pig

for applying a machine learning algorithm, I need to create a word frequency vector. It is like

I: 9
you: 3
good: 2

I generate an empty vector first

I: 0
you: 0
good: 0

then go thru all the documents one by one, counting each word key as they appear in the document. At the end, I should have one vector for each document.

I can generate the empty vector, but how do I process thru each document and increment the word key in the vector?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Pig? There is no variable concept in Pig. There is no initialization neither incrementing the variables support in Pig. Only thing is you can TOKENIZE the input lines and Group the words and you can perform count. 
Refer Apache Pig Latin Book http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch01.html#runs_on_hadoop.
However this will not create a vector

Comment: so, no way to achieve what I want even if I go to UDF?